# Open each link a new p:tab in p:tabView

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tabs, tabview

I use PrimeFaces 6.0 and jsf 2.0. I have implemented the datatable search result in searchAll.xhtml page and edit.xhtml to display the detail of each row of datatable, the scope of SearchBean is view scope. Now I want to open every row in new p:tab of p:tabView? My question what is the best scope bean for this? And it is possible to do that (each click open new tab with close button) for all application link, menu, click ?

| Home Tab (x)| Search Tab (x)| Row 1 Detail Tab (x)| Row 2 Detail Tab (x)| Manage User Tab (x)|...

Comment: Currently you can only add a tab by fully updating the `p:tabView`, so all other tabs will be processed/rerendered to (which might be costly). Using e.g. the tabView from Prime-UI in a creative way might be an option to. But besides all this, please file an issue in PrimeFaces github for being able to add a tab without updating the full tabview. It is (with some creativity) possible for them to achieve this (and it would be a real good addition)

Comment: you are right issue done https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1994

Comment: Why not use p:tabmenu? I think it fits better to your use case http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/tabMenu.xhtml